# MySQL Error "an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error from MySQL when inserting data into database:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'leave (apply_date, leave_category, leave_type, from_date, to_date, reason, duty_' at line 1"

I have not received before(I made the same script a little over a week ago and never had this error.

Here follows the code for the "func.php" file

```
function apply_leave($apply_date,$category,$type,$from,$to,$reason,$assign){

  $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO leave (apply_date, leave_category, leave_type, from_date, to_date, reason, duty_assign)
 VALUES ('$apply_date', '$category', '$type', '$from', '$to', '$reason', '$assign')")or die("error on query".mysql_error());
```

---

Here follows the code for the "leave_apply.php" file

```
if(isset($_POST['apply'])){
   $apply_date=$_POST['apply_date'];
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $type=$_POST['type'];
   $from=$_POST['from'];
   $to=$_POST['to'];
   $no_of_date=$_POST['no_of_date'];
   $reason=$_POST['reason'];
   $assign=$_POST['assign'];
   $result=apply_leave($apply_date, $category, $type, $from, $to, $reason, $assign);
```

Comment: missing your database connection variable

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_`or `PDO` with prepared statement

Comment: If an answer solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leave` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `leave` (...)
```